# Get all Current Clients to a wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wsDualHttpBinding WCF , i get the current CallbackChannel by calling:

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IInterfaceCallBack>();
```

it works fine, but i was wondering if there is any way to get all the callbackchannels currently avaiable.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to cache all the callback channel by yourselves.

Comment: yes that is what i do now i cache them in a list but i was hoping for something better